# Comparing current date in object with dates from database

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to check if the currentdate is inside a list with multiple records of my database. The records im getting back are not only dates but also other stuff. If i print the list i get the following as return

```
((0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 29)), (0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 30)), (1L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 31)))
```

The currentdate i state as followed

```
 currentdate = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
 cd_dt = datetime.strptime(currentdate, '%Y/%m/%d').date()
```

Now i try to compare them like this:

```
print(cd_dt in result_set)
```

This returns false even though todays date is inside that list.

How would i fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are trying to match `time` object with a tuple of tuple. If you want to fix your solution you can use the following line to fix:

Change

```
>>> print(cd_dt in result_set)
```

To

```
>>> any(d[1] == cd_dt for d in k)
>>> True
```

You can use builtin [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to filter the result set. In this way you can also get the matched element(s) of result set.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> k = ((0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 29)), (0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 30)), (1L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 31)))
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == datetime.date.today(),k))
>>> [(1L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 31))]
```

Or if you just want to check if the current date is in the result set you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
>>> any(d[1] == datetime.date.today() for d in k)
>>> True
```

Comment: i only need to check if the current day is in the result set so i've tried your any solution. I've put the line  any(d[1] == datetime.date.today() for d in result_set) in a function and printing that result. But this returns: None

Comment: `any` only returns `True` or `False`. Are you sure you are returning the correct result from function?

Comment: You are absolutely right, i made a mistake. I think i can make it work with this! Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

```
List = ((0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 29)), 
        (0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 30)), 
        (1L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 31)))

currentdate = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
cd_dt = datetime.strptime(currentdate, '%Y/%m/%d').date()

return cd_dt in List
```

Try above code. It works.

Comment: Since the code is not inside a function it gives a error with syntaxerror: 'return' outside function

Comment: So you can create a method and try executing the code

Comment: I've tried to this now but this also returns False unfortunately!